# Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I can't run my application. I receive the following error:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "NETScoreCore.Resources.Shared.SharedStrings.resources" was correctly
>   embedded or linked into assembly "NETScoreCore" at compile time, or
>   that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
>   signed.

The code that throws this error is the following line, which ran correctly before, but now throws this error:

```
return ResourceManager.GetString("For_business",resourceCulture);
```

Comment: That looks like an error report. What's the question? How does the source code look? And what version of .NET / VS are you using?

Comment: Are you sure you have a resource file with the correct name?

Comment: yes, resFiles are correct. What else can it be?

Comment: Narik, can you update your question first, please?

Comment: .net 4.0, can't run application.                                                            return ResourceManager.GetString("For_business",resourceCulture);              Shared string on its place, this programm was running befor, but now, it throws this message

Comment: Narik: Welcome at SO. Please know that you can update questions: just click the "edit" link. When answers are posted, you can click "add comment" under them to explain whether it helps or not or to provide extra info. See also the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you don't seem to have asked a question yet, here's an attempt for an answer. Google shows me [this KB article from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318603), it's possible that you just hit that bug.